Any plans for bitcoin documentation?
I am new to this site and wanted to get some knowledge about bitcoins and was wondering if there is any plan for a wiki for this website? just like there is one on stackoverflow.

This won't happen, at least not in the near future. Yesterday, Stack Overflow (the company) has announced that they will phase out Stack Overflow Documentation. So it's highly unlikely it's coming to Bitcoin Stack Exchange.

welcome to Bitcoin.Stackexchange.com. 
I'm not familiar with the "wiki on Stackoverflow". Are you referring to the tag wikis? On Bitcoin.SE, there are a few tag wikis, but unfortunately, at this time the community of the Bitcoin Stackexchange is probably not numerous enough to broadly fill those quickly.
You can find a lot of technical information in the Bitcoin developer reference, and there is a (terribly outdated!) on bitcoin.it.

Hi, i was talking about the documentation that is available on stackoverflow for different technologies. That is really really helpful for new users.

@viCky: Could you link me to an example? I'm puzzled.

sure: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation

I wouldn't mind an example either.  I'm not sure what you are talking about.

@viCky: I'm afraid this is the first time I hear about this, and we've not been notified of pending changes like that to our site. Since it is labeled "beta" on Stackoverflow, I would presume that it is still being tried out, before it will be evaluated further and perhaps rolled out to other stackexchange sites.

Great. Thanks for your time. I hope we soon get documents on all websites.
